# Convergence of a series and its derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence

I have to study punctual, uniform and total  convergence of the following sums
$$u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}\int_0^1\exp(-nxt^4)dt$$
$$v(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_n'(x)$$
I'm looking for exercises of sequences of functions which involve the study of sequences of functions in integral form but I haven't study Lebesgue integrability yet. I'm trying to solve the exercises with a quite standard theory about convergence of function sequences and function series.
I initially found a little bit confusing the fact that the integrand has both the variables $x$ and $t$.
What I've done is considering $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in \mathbb R$. For the punctual convergence I discarded the case $x<0$ because in this case the integrand would be, for $n\to \infty$, $\dfrac{\exp(-nxt^4)}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{e^{nxt^4}n^2}\sim\dfrac{1}{e^{nxt^4}}\to\infty,\forall x\in\mathbb R^-$. At this point I think I can say that since the integral from zero to one can be divergent or can assume a real value, the sum would have a non zero general term so it can't be punctual convergent in $\mathbb R^-$.
For $x\ge 0$ I have $u_n(0)=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\forall n\in\mathbb N$ and I can apply
$$\dfrac{1}{e^{nxt^4}}\le \dfrac{1}{n}\implies u_n\le\dfrac{1}{n^3}\implies \sum u_n\le\sum\dfrac{1}{n^3}$$
so we have punctual, uniform and total convergence in $[0,+\infty)$.
I really have problems with $u'_n(x)$... Shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: $$u_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^1 \exp \left(-n t^4 x\right) \, dt=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{n x}}-\frac{1}{4} E_{\frac{3}{4}}(n x)\right)$$
$$u'_n(x)=\frac{x \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4},n x\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\right)}{4 (n x)^{9/4}}$$where $E_{\alpha}(x)$ is  the exponential integral function

Comment: We've never used the gamma function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusions and general approach for $\sum u_n(x)$ are correct but the arguments have a few errors.

**For $x < 0$**:

You claim that

$$\displaystyle \frac{\exp(-nxt^4)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{e^{nxt^4}n^2}\sim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{nxt^4}},$$

but the symbolism $f(n)\sim g(n)$ means $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)/g(n) = 1$, which is not true in this case.

The correct argument for $x < 0$ is

$$\frac{\exp(-nxt^4)}{n^2}=\frac{\exp(n|x|t^4)}{n^2} > \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{(n|x|t^4)^3}{3!} = \frac{n|x|^3t^{12}}{6},$$

and the series diverges, since,

$$u_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^1\exp(-nxt^4)\, dt > \frac{n |x|^3}{6}\int_0^1 t^{12} \, dt \underset{n \to \infty} \longrightarrow +\infty $$

**For $x \geqslant 0$**:

The inequality $\frac{1}{e^{nxt^4}}\le \frac{1}{n}$ holds eventually for fixed $x$ and $t$, but this can't be used for uniform convergence.

Uniform convergence holds by the Weierstrass M-test simply because $\exp(-nxt^4) \leqslant 1$ and

$$u_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^1\exp(-nxt^4)\, dt \leqslant  \frac{1}{n^2}$$

---

**Regarding $v(x)$**:

We can switch the order of the derivative and integral  to obtain

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1\exp(-nxt^4) \, dt = \int_0^1(-nt^4)\exp(-nxt^4) \, dt,$$

and, thus,

$$v(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty u'_n(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1t^4\exp(-nxt^4) \, dt $$

Using a similar argument as before, the series diverges for $x < 0$. We also have divergence for $x = 0$, since

$$u'_n(0) = - \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 t^4 \, dt = - \frac{1}{5n}$$

For $x > 0$, we have

$$u'_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1t^4\exp(-nxt^4) \, dt < \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{t^4}{nxt^4} \, dt = \frac{1}{n^2x},$$

and it follows that the series converges pointwise and absolutely, as well as uniformly for $x \in [a,\infty)$ for any $a > 0$.

There is one  remaining question that I will leave to you. Does   $\sum u'_n(x)$ converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Alchemist: Let me know if you need help with non-uniform convergence of $v(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: I think that in order to have uniform convergence for $\sum u'_n$ we have to consider sets in $\mathbb R^+$ in which we remove all a neighbourhood of $0$. So we'll have uniform convergence not in $(0,+\infty)$ but in $[0+\delta,+\infty)$

Comment: Also I think we can say that $u(x)\in\mathcal C^1((0,+\infty))$ and in this set it holds the relation $$u'(x)=v(x)$$

Comment: thank you for the super clear answer:-) If you don't mind could you explain me the passages under the integral of the symbols $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ and $\lim$?

Comment: @Alchemist: You're welcome.  The passage of the derivative under the integral to determine $u'_n(x)$ follows from the  [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#:~:text=In%20calculus,%20Leibniz's%20rule%20for%20differentiation%20under%20the,with%20x%20is%20considered%20in%20taking%20the%20derivative.).  It is a particularly simple application here since the integration limits are fixed.  The integrand $\exp(-nxt^4)$ is everywhere continuous as a function of $x,t$ and continuously differentiable with respect to $x$ so we have strong sufficient conditions for this.

Comment: In general to prove for $F(x) = \int_a^bf(x,t) \, dt$ that $F'(x) = \int_a^b f_x(x,t) \, dt$, you show that $\lim_{h \to 0}\int_a^b \frac{f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)}{h} \, dt = \int_a^b \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)}{h} \, dt$.  This can be done in a variety of ways. Here we can use the mean value theorem $f(x+h,t) - f(x,t) = f_x(\xi,t) h$ where $\xi \to x$ as $h \to 0$ and the continuity if the derivative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in general when we have a sum of a squence of integral function we first study the integrand (and if it's possible we try to find a term to estimate it) in order to understand how it behaves in a neighbourhood of a singularity of the domain. If the interval of integration also depends by $n$ and $x$ we try to find a primitive of the function that estimate the integrand and then we study its limits for $x$ fixed and $n\to\infty$ for punctual convergence. For the uniform convergence it's quite similar because we've already found a  majorant...